# Getting different results executing query in PHP and directly to database

Tags: php, mysql

Using phpMyAdmin and running the following query I get 19 registers:

```
SELECT * FROM trayecto tr, lugar lu WHERE idAeropuerto = '3' AND tr.idLugar = lu.idLugar GROUP BY tr.idAeropuerto, tr.idLugar ORDER BY lu.nombre
```

but running this query in the website obtaining the data throw and PHP call I only get 18 registers (all of them but the last one entered in the database).

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
include('init_bd.php');
$selectLugaresDeAeropuerto="SELECT * FROM trayecto tr, lugar lu WHERE idAeropuerto = '".$q."' AND tr.idLugar = lu.idLugar GROUP BY tr.idAeropuerto, tr.idLugar ORDER BY lu.nombre";
$resultLugaresDeAeropuerto = mysql_query($selectLugaresDeAeropuerto) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());
echo "<SELECT SIZE='1' NAME='Lugar'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultLugaresDeAeropuerto))
{
  printf("<OPTION VALUE=%s>%s</OPTION>", $row["idLugar"], $row["nombre"]);    
}
echo " </SELECT>";
mysql_free_result($resultLugaresDeAeropuerto);
include('close_bd.php');
```

You can execute this PHP to see the result:
http://www.transferbus.com/bd/getLugar.php?q=3

I have a MySQL Database with the following tables and structure:

**TRAYECTO**

```
idAeropuerto - int(8)
idLugar - int(8)
idTipoTransporte - int(8)
precio - double
tiempo - varchar(5)
distancia - varchar(5)
```

**LUGAR**

```
idLugar - int(8) - auto_increment
nombre - varchar(40)
```

Any idea why I get different results with same-like query?

Comment: Are you querying the same database? The most common reason for the same query giving two different results in two different environments is that you are connecting to two different databases.

Comment: http://www.transferbus.com/bd/getLugar.php?q=3 is broken link

Comment: @Mark I only have one database.

Sorry, but website is temporarily down (that's what my hosting provider said).

Comment: @Manel: It is a very common error to think you have only one database, when actually you have two. This happens especially if you are using a new web provider that you are unfamiliar with. To see if this is the case, try modifying one of the displayed strings via phpMyAdmin and check that the change is visible in your webpage. If the change is not visible then you may be accessing two different databases.

Comment: @MarkByers I have changed one of the names that appear in the combo and I don't see the new value, but I only have one database and it seems to be accessing it. I will contact the hosting service provider and check everything is ok.

Comment: @Manel: "I only have one database" I'm not convinced... your observations seem to imply that you have two databases. Having two databases is also the most frequent cause of this type of error.

Comment: @MarkByers You were absolutely right. My hosting did a backup and the link of phpMyAdmin was directing to this backup, instead of the real database.

Comment: @Manel: I suspected as much. I can post it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to two different databases. Contact your web provider if you need help with connecting to the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script you're querying the number 3 as a string (with quotes) Although you defined your table as an int(8).

str(3) is not the same as int(3)

Besides that: Please read something on the internet about SQL injection. 
Passing your $_GET['q'] directly to the database server is not very smart!

Comment: I simplified the PHP file to a minimum. In the full-version I check type and size of the parameter before using the variable in the query. But, thank you for the advice.

Comment: But this is what you query: `idAeropuerto = '3'` while your database is setup to be using an int(8) a '3' is not a 3 and grouping on them can give different results.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Using `WHERE idAeropuerto = '3'` should work too.